# Dynamic Pivot to sum and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I was trying to do a dynamic pivot on two columns to rearrange some data. Her is my original table:

[**Initial table**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgvh8.png)

I used the flowing code to pivot the **BRAND** based on **CountryID** and **GenericArticle** but I get following result (as you can see the table doesn't seem to be GROUPed BY)

[**Result after pivot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io79Y.png)

Here is my Pivot Code:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Brand)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Brand]
      FROM #tempProgCov) AS Country

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT [CountryID], [GenericArticle], ' + @ColumnName + '
INTO ##ProgCovPivot
FROM #tempProgCov as Src
PIVOT
 (
    SUM([Coverage])
    FOR [Brand] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
 ) as Pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

PS, was expecting something like this:

[**Desired result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slZeB.png)

Comment: If you tagged with sqlserver rather than MySQL you might have attracted attention from that community

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

Answer (score 0):

Never-mind, I solved it eventually, was just under my eye. Problem was in source table select:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Brand)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Brand]
      FROM #tempProgCov) AS Country

SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT [CountryID], [GenericArticle], ' + @ColumnName + '
INTO ##ProgCovPivot
FROM (SELECT CountryID,
             Brand,
             GenericArticle,
             Coverage
      FROM #tempProgCov) as Src
PIVOT
 (
    SUM([Coverage])
    FOR [Brand] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')
 ) as Pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```